# Homestead 2.0 giving issues on Yosemite

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have this strange problem. Let me describe it:

1. The mapping on the .yaml doesn't work. forum.app will just open up a Google search.
2. The debug is set to true for local, yet, errors aren't presented in browser. They're logged though.

I am using Homestead 2.0, Laravel 4 (everything is latest) on a Yosemite (updated today). The code is here:

```
YAML file

---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/aligajani/Dropbox/Work/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: forum.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/CommunityFT/forum/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local


HOSTS file

#Added by XAMPP Control
127.0.0.1 Alis-MacBook-Pro.local
192.168.10.10  forum.app
```

Comment: Have you tried to run `vagrant provision` ? And are you sure you are editing correct yaml file?

Comment: How can I be sure I'm editing the correct yaml file? And no that doesn't work. I destroy and do up though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `forum.app` to be a valid domain that works with Homestead, you'll need to point it to your local computer in your hosts file.

You can do this by opening up terminal, and typing `vim /etc/hosts`, then add the line:

```
127.0.0.1 forum.app
```

Your browser may fail to look up the forum.app domain too, so remember to try adding a forward slash teh first time you visit it, so `forum.app/`, this will prevent the browser trying to google it.

Errors not being presented to the browser **may** be something to do with this pull request:

https://github.com/laravel/homestead/pull/140

Which is an Nginx configuration issue.

Hope this helps!